# Android How To create RadioButtons like a row of Buttons

Tags: android, styles, radio-button

In My app i have a search option for stores. I can do the search with two criteria: By Name and By Distance.
The user can choose only one of them.
The required "shape" is
[image: Search layout]

The required RadioButtons marked by the red "circle".
How it can be done?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: Have you tred setting the drawable in the xml?  I know you can do this, i'm not sure whether or not it will do exactly what you want but might be a good place to start.  If not you can just implement your own radio button and overwrite onDraw with your specified stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your radiobutton in xml to something like this

```
<RadioButton
 android:id="@+id/radio0"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/customradiobutton"
 android:button="@android:color/transparent"
 android:checked="true"
 android:text="RadioButton1" />
```

And for customradiobutton you can add

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/checked_image"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked_image" />
```

Another better idea would to use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) instead of RadioButtons

Answer (score 0):

Use ToggleButtons

```
<ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toggle"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"/>
```